# jQuery text loading animation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Trying to make a text ... loading animation

here's where I stand: http://jsfiddle.net/aGfct/

I can get the ... to be added at 500 ms intervals, but then I want to remove them and then start the animation over / until loading is done (basically it can loop forever, and I will fade it out when done).

Any help would be great.

Thanks.

_charlie

Comment: No need for a gif. I just want to have the dots "animation" cycle until loaded.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

```
i = 0;
setInterval(function() {
    i = ++i % 4;
    $("#loading").html("loading"+Array(i+1).join("."));
}, 500);
```

If you wish to change the string after 5 says, that's after 10 iterations. This can be accomplished like this.

```
i = 0;
text = "loading";
setInterval(function() {
    $("#loading").html(text+Array((++i % 4)+1).join("."));
    if (i===10) text = "start";
}, 500);
```

Answer (score 7):

http://jsfiddle.net/paska/aGfct/12/

```
var originalText = $("#loading").text(),
    i  = 0;
setInterval(function() {

    $("#loading").append(".");
    i++;

    if(i == 4)
    {
        $("#loading").html(originalText);
        i = 0;
    }

}, 500);
```

Answer (score 3):

I have a solution very similar like roXon, only in my case 2 features I have added.

1. Just add an blank elemnt with id=loadingDots, like span id="loadingDots">
2. Add the function call in document.ready. Now in my case I needed to display the loading dots in some pages but not all. So, the function will look for the element with id=loadingDots, and if not found, will clear the interval.

[Demo in JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kCH92/8/)

[HTML]

```
<!--Just have an element with id=loadingDots-->
<span style="font-size:42px">Sending<span id="loadingDots"></span></span>
```

[JS]

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    /**Call the function in document.ready somewhere*/
    showLoadingDots();
});
```

The function

```
var showLoadingDots = function() {
    /**If element not found, do nothing*/
    if (!$("#loadingDots").length>0) return false;

    var showDots = setInterval(function(){            
        //Thanks to roXon, StackOverflow
        var d = $("#loadingDots");
        d.text().length >= 3 ? d.text('') : d.append('.');
    },300);
}
```

Hope it helps somebody. Thanks roXon, for ideas.

Answer (score 2):

Try using setInterval also so like:

```
setInterval(function(){
    for (i = 1; i <= 3; i++) {
        setTimeout(function() {
        $("#loading").append(".");
        }, i * 500);
    }
    $("#loading").html('loading');
}, 2000);
```

Comment: you can also assign the whole thing to a variable, and clearInterval(myvar); when you're done

Comment: I think this approach is very complex, check out my simpler code: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8537581/310276

Answer (score 1):

Just add this line at the end of your loop:

```
i = (i === 3) ? 0 : i;
```

That's just shorthand for saying 'if `i` is equal to 3, set it back to zero, else leave it as it is'. That should kick off your loop all over again until you set an exit condition.

**EDIT**: Hold on, I didn't actually look at how you appended the `.`(sorry, can't get jsFiddle to run anything at the moment)! If you were to use the `i` reset as above, you'd really need to set the number of `.` characters equal to `i` with every iteration.

**EDIT 2**: Looking again, you'd even need to take `i` into a closure to get its value at the time the `setTimeout` is **declared**, otherwise you'll get whatever value it is when `setTimeout` is **executed**, which is unpredictable.  Basically, don't use this solution - use Jeff's! ;)

Comment: @Andrew yes it will, which the OP mentioned isn't a problem. Because of the `setTimeout` call, each loop execution will get pushed to the end of the stack, so it shouldn't lock up the UI, but yeah it is worth watching.

Comment: @ChrisFrancis It will lock up the UI. You're making an infinite queue of `setTimeout`s. The JS engine doesn't wait for each timeout to be executed before adding a new one. Use `setInterval` if you want the engine to wait.

Comment: Yeah, moving the loop **inside** `setInterval` would be much better - luckily somebody smarter than me has already posted that! ;)