# How do I use repeated value in innerhtml?

Tags: javascript

## I used this code but it's not repeat

it increase the value but don't get to the initial value 0
please help

```
   i=0;
        function loading()
        {
            text=["Loading.","Loading..","Loading...","Loading...."];
            window.setInterval(wr(),500)
        }
        function wr()
        {
            if(i<4)
            {
                wr='document.getElementById("text").innerHTML=text[i]';
                alert(i);
            }
            else
                i=0;    
            return wr;
        }
```

Comment: Oh wow. That's a confusing way to pass code to `setInterval`. Apart from that "mess", you are never increasing `i`.

Comment: How can so many things go wrong in so little code?

Comment: Also, `wr()` is a function that upon running once, overrides itself with a string.

Answer (score 2):

Your code is way to complicated. Define a simple function which you pass to `setInterval` and make sure you increase the counter variable:

```
var i = 0; // initialize counter
var textElement =  document.getElementById("text");
setInterval(function() {
    i = i % 4; // make sure `i` is at max 3 and reset to 0
    var text = 'Loading';
    for (var j = i; j--; ) {
        text += '.'; // add the correct number of periods
    }
    textElement.innerHTML = text; // set text
    i++; // increase counter
}, 500);
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/ypUS9/)

Answer (score 1):

Here's a slight modification of a [similar answer I gave a while back](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8537358/jquery-text-loading-animation/8537672#8537672).

```
var i = 0;
setInterval(function() {
    i = ++i % 4;
    document.getElementById('text').innerHTML = "Loading"+Array(i+1).join(".");
}, 500);
```